# How to create transparent command bar in Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1

how to create transparent command bar in Windows Phone 8.1
Here is xaml

```
<Page x:Class="App3.MainPage"
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
  xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"      
  xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
  Background="White"      
  mc:Ignorable="d">

<Grid Background="Red" />

<Page.BottomAppBar>
    <CommandBar Background="#CCFFFFFF" Foreground="Black">
        <CommandBar.PrimaryCommands>
            <AppBarButton Label="Button1" />
        </CommandBar.PrimaryCommands>
    </CommandBar>
</Page.BottomAppBar>
```

When CommandBar is open, it has a transparent background, but there is a white panel behind. Hot to remove this panel?

Comment: Wouldn't the fact that your Page has `Background="White"` be a hint as to where that's coming from?

Comment: Not exactly. But your answer gave me an idea. I solved the problem like this: 
<Grid Background="Red" Margin="0,0,0,-60" />

Answer (score 9):

Use this code in App.xaml.cs, OnLaunched Method, before Window.Current.Activate();

```
Windows.UI.ViewManagement.ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView().SetDesiredBoundsMode(
ApplicationViewBoundsMode.UseCoreWindow);
```

EDIT : Bydefault, the framework layouts the window's content within the visible region only. Hence, when you expanded the appbar, it shows the basecolor(black/white) behind it eventhough you set the appbar transparent. So if you want to make use of entire page window, you have to use the above code, which sets core window across the entire app.

Comment: Can you explain this solution?

Answer (score 1):

By changing the opacity you can make the commandbar transparent or add an x:Name to commandbar 
if you want to change background to tranparent

```
<CommandBar Background="#CCFFFFFF" Foreground="Black" x:name="op" opacity=0.4>
//and in the code
//add 
op.Background = new SolidnewBrush(Windows.UI.Colors.Transparent);`
```

Comment: When i make the background opacity the whole content gets opacity too. Its there any way to avoid it? In my case I need the background only not the content.